# Live Wallpaper with bouncing effect

Tags: java, android, eclipse, live-wallpaper

I'm creating a life wallpaper for android which "ic_launcher" is able to bounce when it "hit" the left/right edge of the screen.

```
    public class LiveWallpaperService extends WallpaperService 
    {
            int x,y;

            public void onCreate()
            {
                    super.onCreate();
            }

            public void onDestroy() 
            {
                    super.onDestroy();
            }

            public Engine onCreateEngine() 
            {
                    return new MyWallpaperEngine();
            }

            class MyWallpaperEngine extends Engine 
            {

                    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            draw();
                        }
                    };
                    private boolean visible = true;
                    public Bitmap image1,backgroundImage;

                    MyWallpaperEngine() 
                    {

                            image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                            backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.pika);
                            x=130; 
                            y=200;  

                    }


                    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
                    {
                            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible)
                    {
                            this.visible = visible;

                            if (visible) 
                            {
                                handler.post(drawRunner);
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
                    {
                            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
                            this.visible = false;
                            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
                    }

                    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) 
                    {
                            draw();
                    }

                    void draw() 
                    {
                            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
                            int xVelocity = 10;

                            Canvas c = null;
                            try 
                            {
                                    c = holder.lockCanvas();

                                    c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                                    if (c != null)
                                    {

                                            c.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);

                                            c.drawBitmap(image1, x,y, null);

                                            int width=c.getWidth();
                                            x += xVelocity;


                                            if(x>=width) 

                                            {xVelocity = -xVelocity;
                                            }


                                            }


                            }
                            finally 
                            {
                                    if (c != null)
                                           holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                            }

                            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
                            if (visible) 
                            {
                                      handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 10); 
                            }    

                    }
            }
    }
```

The ic_launcher won't bounce back when it met the edge of the screen(it just keep moving to the right until I can't see it any more), can some one help me about it? I guess the problem is in this few lines

```
    int width=c.getWidth();
    x += xVelocity;

    if(x>=width) 
    {xVelocity = -xVelocity;
    }

    }
```

I'm still a newbie in android programming, Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: see if setting `xVelocity = -10` helps, when x is greater than width. Its possible that it is going off screen, then being inversed constantly, to the point it is not moving. Test this is not the case with -10.

Comment: Nope, it's still run off the screen. But to the left this time

Comment: See my answer, so i can better show where i meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from your comments: you are resetting velocity each time you call `draw()`;

move 
`int xVelocity = 10;`

so it is at the top with  `int x,y;`

```
 int x,y;
 int xVelocity = 10;
 int velValue = 10;
 int velInvValue = -10;
```

Then keep some better inverse code like:

```
if(x >= width)
{
      xVelocity = velInvValue;
}
else if(x <= 0)
{
      xVelocity = velValue;
}
x += xVelocity;
```

Comment: @user3548900 Does it bounce on the right side though? You have not written the bounce for left side. See edit.

Comment: It goes to the right at the beginning, when it met the right edge of the screen, it won't bounce.

Comment: I guess eclipse can't define my "width".

Comment: maybe, this line it the problem
int width=c.getWidth();

Comment: @user3548900 Try the last code section in my edit. What is the value of width if you debug?

Comment: It's still can't bounce...
Sorry, how can I get the value and how can I debug? I'm quite new in this area

Comment: You need to debug the values then, as Im testing blind. Try `if(x >= 260)`.

Comment: wow, now eclipse really can't define my width=c.getwidth()
The icon goes to the right then vibrate in the middle of the screen.

Comment: @user3548900 it will vibrate if it is constantly inversing. Which is what I assumed was happening off screen. :/  from that info i can now see a major flaw in your code. Velocity is being reset to `int xVelocity = 10;` in every `draw()` call. This needs to set at the very top, under `int x,y;`

Comment: With your edited code, it run out the screen again.
I decided to not add in int x,y; as it asked me to have some initial number. When I add in some number inside int x = 100 then it stop moving

Comment: @user3548900 did you remove `int xVelocity = 10;` from `draw()` ... This should be working

Comment: @user3548900 You cannot specify x or y directly inside `draw()` or they will never change.. hence never move. You need to put velocity at the very top with x and y. NOT x and y with velocity in draw

Comment: oh, now I get you mean. I tot you were asking me to add in those code in draw(). By the way, how can i get the width of my ic-launcher? I remember there is a code similar to this one.
ic_width = c.image1().getwidth()

Comment: Thanks! I have learnt a lot's of thing from you. :)
All the BEST :D

Comment: @user3548900 Glad to know I was of help :) Happy coding.